# What setup to only copy files

Tags: .net, installation, setup-project

I need to create a setup in vs 2010 which would copy files to specific folders. Which setup project type should I use to accomplish that?

I am thinking about creating a console application to find the folders and copy the files into them. Am I going in the right direction, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please be more specific in what the rest of the program will do. Are you using a GUI? Are you only making a text-based program?

Comment: I have from a client 2 files and he wants copy them into folders in program files which in its name have "\experts\indicators" text. So I don't need any GUI, or  a console application. Those files would be used by some MetaTrader program(not mine). I just need to create nice setup to copy those files. There is a problem, that clients of my client use different metatrader platform, but every of this platform has folder experts and indicators

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Setup project to generate an MSI package:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317(VS.90).aspx

This thread may also help:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473

Answer (score 0):

You could also just provide a simple Powershell script to copy the files needed. A kind of xcopy deployment. If you don't need a GUI for the deployment process itself.